# why can I run 2 or more http servers (with different ports) in one process

Tags: node.js, express

It only has 1 node process in my Windows7 task manager. Surprise. How nodejs achieve this and What the difference if I split servers in difference processes? Thanks.

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
     res.end('Hello World'); 
}).listen(5000, '127.0.0.1');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
     res.end('Hello World2');
}).listen(5001, '127.0.0.1');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
     res.end('Hello World3');
}).listen(5002, '127.0.0.1');
```

Answer (score 0):

A single process can open as many sockets as the OS allows it to. As long as it does not try to open a socket on a port which is already taken by another socket.

One difference would be that you have one thread running for each server instead of one thread for all three servers, since Node only runs one thread per process. This can be relevant to you if you have issues with performance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a multitasking system, nodejs can have one or more threads per port.

The advantage of having a single nodejs process handle multiple ports is that you save a tiny bit of RAM.

The disadvantage is that when one server crashes, both "servers" might be affected.